# Javascript wildcard inside of condition?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I have a basic javascript conditional statement for filtering through some items, it looks like this:

```
if(item == var_condition) { //do this }
```

Now what I would like for the `var_condition` is, if I have a variable condition available than `var_condition = my condition`, but if I don't have a condition available than `var_condition = *`, meaning item could equal anything.

Is there a way this can be done? when I try: `if(item == "*")` it returns no results.

Thank you

Comment: If you want it to happen for everything, why do you even need a conditional?  Just perform your operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
if(!var_condition || item == var_condition) {//do this }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
if(item === (var_condition || item)) { /*do this*/}
```